# Rank of a product between a full row and a full column rank matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-rank

$\def\rank{\operatorname{rank}}$
Suppose that matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, m<n$ is a full row rank matrix, while  $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is a full column rank matrix. Is product $AB$ a regular matrix?

I have experienced this problem while trying to solve a linear system $b = ABx + c$, where $x$ is unknown $m$-dimensional vector, while $A$ and $B$ are matrices with their properties stated above.

Comment: I tried to give context of my problem and I added a tag, to try to remove "off-topic" problem.

Answer (score 4):

Take $A=(1,1)$ and $B=\left(\begin{array}{r}1 \\ -1\end{array}\right).$ Both matrix have rank $1.$ Is it regular the matrix $AB=(0)?$

Comment: Your example shows it is not valid in general. However, now I do not understand what is wrong with the answer from Sami Ben.

Answer (score 2):

If $\exists v\in null(A):\exists x:Bx=v$, then $rank(AB)<m$, else $rank(AB)=m$.

Comment: Minor point: You should exclude $v=0$ from $null(A)$.